# No sound on PowerMac G5 with Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, mate, powerpc

I am aware that the sound issue with PPC G5s (PowerPC) has been discussed in quite a few posts in several forums and communities and it was marked "Fixed". But these solutions do not work for me / on my box.

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on my G5 PPC, dual booting with OS X 10.5.8. Everything looked and worked pretty well after installation, with the exception of sound and WiFi.

Regarding sound I had the typical phenomenon with "dummy audio" being said and no audio device listed in system settings. Alsamixer crashed when selecting *Edit » Sound Card Properties* obviously because there was no sound card recognised.

The [PowerPC FAQ](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ) says the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local.conf` should be deleted, but I do not have such file on my system. What I have is a `blacklist.conf` and seven more blacklists in this directory, but none of those seems to adress sound.

I added the following to `/etc/modules`:

```
snd_aoa_i2sbus
snd_aoa_fabric_layout
snd_aoa_codec_tas
snd_aoa_codec_onyx
```

As a result there is now a sound card listed in settings:

> K2 KeyLargo Mac/IO

Both in settings and ALSA the device can be edited. But still no sound what ever the settings are.

In OS X it says the sound card is a **Texas Instruments TAS3004.** How do I get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post the output of `cat /proc/device-tree/model` and `find /proc/device-tree/ -name layout-id | xargs hexdump -e '1/4 "0x%x\n"'` as [specified here](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Aoa).

Comment: thx Andrea. Will post this output right away. Although I got sound working after DELETING the entry:
snd_aoa_codec_onyx
from /etc/modules and leaving only the entries snd_aoa
snd_aoa_soundbus
snd_aoa_i2sbus
snd_aoa_fabric_layout
snd_aoa_codec_tas
added. I followed an advise from "tomi" on ubuntu-mate.community.

Comment: +Andrea, here is the output as requested (indented): 

cat /proc/device-tree/model
   PowerMac7,3

find /proc/device-tree/ -name layout-id | xargs hexdump -e '1/4 "0x%x\n"'
   0x24

Does that help? As I said in previous comment: I got sound working following an advise on ubuntu-mate but it is a bit frustrating for me as I do not understand what I am actually doing by adding or deleting these entries.

Comment: If you solved the question do not leave the solution as a comment. Please write a self answer instead. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. As recommendations and fixes given in several forums look a bit inconsistent to me this answer explains what I did for the fix.

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my PPC G5 there was only one entry in the file `/etc/modules` (i.e. kernel modules to load at boot time):

```
apm_emu
```

The following entries (and only these) need to be added to `/etc/modules`:

```
snd_aoa
snd_aoa_soundbus
snd_aoa_i2sbus
snd_aoa_fabric_layout
snd_aoa_codec_tas
```

**Do not** make an entry:

```
snd_aoa_codec_onyx
```

In *Terminal* start `gnome-alsamixer`. Check if there is something set on "mute". If this is the case, unmute it. Check the sound levels. Be aware that the sliders show the respective levels the other way round compared to *System → Settings → Sound*.

If a slider is at the top position (and the trail of the slider is all grey, not green) then it is set to 100%. Adjust both *Master* and *PCM* to 100%. With a setting of 70% or less I did not have any signal at the speakers in the next step. *Headphone Detect Autoswitch* and *Line-Out Detect Autodetect* should be selected.

Then close alsamixer and go to:

> System → Settings → Sound

There should now be a sound card listed on the device tab. In my case it is *K2 KeyLargo Mac/IO* (which is odd as in Mac OS X it says *Texas Instruments TAS3004*). On the *Sound effects* tab warnings might be leveled to zero or muted. Adjust as needed but this will probably be set to zero and/or muted each time after startup.

On the *Device* tab you can select a device. In my case I have 4 options to chose from:

1. Analog Stereo Duplex
2. Analog Stereo Output
3. Analog Stereo Input
4. Off

Between the two first I could not identify any differences both with headphones connected in the front and speakers connected in the rear of the G5. Click on *Speakers Test* right next to the selection list. On the next screen you should see something like *Front Left* and *Front Right* probably depending on what you have connected with two respective *Test* buttons.